# Cannot edit php5.fcgi owned by Me with RWX owner permissions

Tags: permissions, gedit, chmod, chown, nano

Ok, I kind of thought I understood Linux permissions and then I encountered this one.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a virtualbox on my Windows 7 pro laptop.  All udpates are applied to windows, virtualbox and ubuntu.

I have used the virtualmin 4.12 gpl install script to set up virtual hosting - again, all updates have been applied.

I want to edit the php5.fcgi file in /home/staging/fcgi-bin to extend the timeout values controlling the php5 script executions.  when using ls -l the directory /home/staging/fcgi-bin is owned by staging:staging and permissions are drwxr-xr-x and the file php5.fcgi is owned by staging:staging with permissions -rwxr-xr-x.  WHen looking at them via the files gui they both show up as owned by "Me" and grouped in staging with the same permissions that ls -l shows. Through files the directory does not show any lock but the php5.fcgi has a small lock icon overlaying the file icon.

Ok, I can open, read and find the file, I believe that I can execute it as that is how my php scripts are run.  However, I cannot save any changes through gedit or nano even when I use sudo to run them.  gedit always shows the save icon as greyed out/not available.  nano reads the file in and allows me to modify it but when I try to save it I get a permission denied error.

I tried to rename and change the ownership and permissions but mv, sudo mv, chown, chmod, sudo chown and sudo chmod all fail with operation not allowed.

When I look to see if the file is opened with lsof | grep "php" I get nothing listed and I think this means the file is not opened.

So I am baffled and really could use some help.  I do not understand how the file gets locked if it is not open and I do not understand why I cannot modify the file in any manner if I am the owner of the file and have rwx permission.

Answer (score 4):

If Linux permissions were not complicated enough, I just learned about extended attributes.  Turns out there is this thing called an immutable attribute.  Using `lsattr php5.fcgi` shows the i(mmutable) attribute is set.  Using `chattr -i php5.fcgi` allowed me to save modifications then `chattr +i php5.fcgi` to restore the immutable attribute.

Who knew!

Comment: Also look up ACLs, just for fun.

Comment: Oh you saved me a lot of time! Correct answer. But I'll never ever use `chattr +i php5.fcgi` to restore this problem again!